# The procedure 'sys.sp_addlinkedserver' cannot be executed because it is not supported in Azure SQL Edge

Tags: sql-server, azure, docker

I'm trying to setup a environment to do some integration testing.

The environment I try to emulate contains a cluster of mssql server instances that are configured as one master machine and a couple of linked servers acting as slaves. The script interacting with the databases uses the master to query the slaves.

As my machine is a new mac I have to use following docker image to be able to run on the M chip:
mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge:latest

I use docker compose to setup 2 databases using the above image.
When trying to create a linked server using sql I get the error:
The procedure 'sys.sp_addlinkedserver' cannot be executed because it is not supported in Azure SQL Edge.

The documentation everywhere does not mention this problem.

Anyone any idea why this is not working or an alternative to the setup I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: *"Anyone any idea why this is not working or an alternative to the setup I'm trying to achieve?"* The error is *literally* telling you the reason: "it is not supported in Azure SQL Edge" There is no work around in Azure SQL Edge. You will need to use a "full" version of SQL Server.

Comment: I suppose it depends on which documentation you're reading. According to [Supported features of Azure SQL Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql-edge/features), _Database Engine > Linked servers_ is in the unsupported features list.

Comment: Also if you wish to run [mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) on macOS 13 Ventura-based systems with M1/M2 processors, you might wish to install Docker Desktop v4.16 and Rosetta 2 and have a read through [Development with SQL in containers on macOS](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sql/development-with-sql-in-containers-on-macos/).

Comment: Omg I already found this documentation page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql-edge/features and brainlessly CTRL-F completely missing the 'unsupported' title and assumed I was looking at a feature list. Thanks for the replies. I want my Linux machine back :(